# Will Ubuntu 16.04 support the rtl8192eu chipset out of the box?

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless, 16.04

I'm now using MINT 17.3 with kernel 3.19.0-32-generic, because the drivers for the rtl8192eu wireless chipset are only available for the 3.x series of kernel.  It does not function on 4.x based kernels.  Why is this, and will Ubuntu 16.04 support it OOTB?

Comment: Wrong place to ask: ask this on launchpad with a bug report or create a feature request. People who can answer this and -fix- this for you are there, not here.

Comment: I fixed this issue by creating a PPA with that driver.

Answer (score 3):

It will not be supported out of the box, but the driver can be installed this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

Comment: For some reason, this ppa didn't work for me in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running Linux 4.4.0-34-generic kernel. Hence, I worked on the sources myself to get the job done. Link: https://github.com/ramsudharsan/rtl8192eu

Comment: Now this PPA works on 4.4. I fixed all issues and added a new version of the driver. But you should use the deb for Xenial.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've installed the driver using the method above, however when I restart my computer it only works if I manually reload the kernel module. I am using the current version of linux mint.

Answer (score 0):

I installed 16.04 a month ago to see how it works, what is new, etc. There is no driver for rtl8192eu out of the box in it.

However I am always compiling the driver to be able to use my rtl8192eu. When kernel evolve some changes are required sometimes in the driver to be compiled for the latest kernel. I have made some minor changes to the driver again and it compiles in 16.04 for the kernel provided with this OS. If you want I can send you the source, which compiles and runs in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You'd better install it with DKMS. I made a PPA with that driver that builds for kernels 4.4. https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192eu-dkms_4.3.1.1.11320.20140505~xenial1_all.deb

Comment: @Pilot6 That is very nice. I have never found a time to learn how to make mine to work with DKMS. I have found some drivers supporting DKMS, but all that I found, were older version and I wanted to use the latest driver I was able to find. I have sources with version number v4.3.8_12406_20140929. I am not 100% sure they are the latest. At least they give me the feeling I am using the latest driver.

Comment: Where did you get those sources. I can use them for a package. But they need to be patched for kernel 4.4.

Comment: I don't remember where I got them. I can send them to you.

Comment: You can upload them somewhere and post a link.

Comment: Here you have the driver. This the complete original package with release notes and everything: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z903st5i1lhco5v/linux%20driver%20for%20XC1289.rar?dl=0 and this is the changed driver for linux which compiles in kernel 4.4: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9g6ad191wfxa27/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.8_12406.20140929.tgz?dl=0

Comment: Thx. I will update the PPA.

Comment: I added it to the PPA. It will build in a while. Please test it.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192eu-dkms_4.3.8.12406.20140929~xenial1_all.deb