# Ubuntu keeps on showing an internal error with package rtl8192eu-dkms 4.4

Tags: drivers, 18.04, ppa, realtek

I have tried installing [this ppa](https://askubuntu.com/a/752843/719469) but it does not have a release file and would not work for 18.04. Is there any solution for solving this or stopping Ubuntu from showing this annoying error:

[image: crash report]

Comment: If the ppa does not support 18.04 there is no way to change that as a user of the ppa. You must obtain the package elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to find any package for rtl8192eu-dkms 4.4, is there any way I stop receiving this error?

Comment: Have you removed the ppa?  You could try ppa-purge https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/

Comment: I've disabled the ppa drom software and updates, but my problem is not the linked ppa, it is this internal error i'm getting due to the driver