# Tenda U1 wireless network adapter works during setup, but afterwards I get "Activation of Network Connection failed"

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet

I recently bought [a Tenda U1 USB wifi card](https://www.tendacn.com/en/product/U1.html) for my desktop computer.

I choose this one because it supports Linux systems. I am new to Ubuntu and trying to understand things about the OS.

When I initiated the Ubuntu 20.04 setup, I successfully connected to my home WiFi and it start working perfectly fine. But when setup had ended and after the reboot, when I tried to connect to WiFi, the system raised an error:

> Activation of Network Connection failed.

After a couple of weeks, I tried rebooting the computer again, and it started working just fine. But the next day, it stopped working and started giving me the same error. So I looked for solutions, and realized I must install the driver from the product's site.

If I have to install the driver, how come the computer established a connection successfully during setup? And why did it start working after I rebooted?

I visited the product's website, and looked for a driver for my adapter. [Adapter's Driver Page](https://www.tendacn.com/en/product/support/U1.html)

I downloaded the file, but since I don't know how to install it properly, I haven't done anything yet. Should I install it? If so, I need an explanation of how to do that.

I looked at Network Manager's logs using the command: `journalctl -u NetworkManager`

The specific line of error from logs:

```
Oca 08 17:29:06 Fulcrum-PC NetworkManager[638]: <warn>  [1610116146.2406] device (wlx502b73cb05d1): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Oca 08 17:29:06 Fulcrum-PC NetworkManager[638]: <info>  [1610116146.2408] device (wlx502b73cb05d1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oca 08 17:29:06 Fulcrum-PC NetworkManager[638]: <info>  [1610116146.2422] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oca 08 17:29:06 Fulcrum-PC NetworkManager[638]: <warn>  [1610116146.2452] device (wlx502b73cb05d1): Activation: failed for connection 'Gelincik'
Oca 08 17:29:06 Fulcrum-PC NetworkManager[638]: <info>  [1610116146.2463] device (wlx502b73cb05d1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

This is the output of `sudo lsusb -v`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192EU 802.11b/g/n WLAN Adapter
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x818b RTL8192EU 802.11b/g/n WLAN Adapter
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek 
  iProduct                2 802.lnn NIC 
  iSerial                 3 00e04c000001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0035
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           5
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 802.lnn NIC 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x000c
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      HIRD Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

This is the `ifconfig`:

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e0:cb:4e:d5:ce:a9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 507  bytes 65206 (65.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 507  bytes 65206 (65.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx502b73cb05d1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.23  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::90a0:6042:14ed:9ce9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 50:2b:73:cb:05:d1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 51411  bytes 73180912 (73.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 93  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23814  bytes 2234380 (2.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Why is network manager failing? Should I set Network Manager's config or install the proper driver for my Wifi adapter? And if it's the driver, how can I properly install the matching driver for my usbWlan card? Thank you.

Comment: can you give us the output of `lsusb -v`?

Comment: i added it. should i add an ifconfig?

Comment: yes please.  can you re-add the `lsusb -v` run under `sudo`? please.

Comment: i changed it. is there anything else should i add?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/832087/how-to-install-tp-link-wn822n-on-ubuntu/832092#832092 can you take a look at this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem but in a different manner. Like, when I connected the tenda U1 with my system, it was picking up the wireless connections and showing the available wifi networks. But when I wanted to connect the wifi and give credentials , it was not connecting and giving the result in failure.
So, I used these commands and now it's connecting and working fine with the installed driver.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

I found this solution here:
[Will Ubuntu 16.04 support the rtl8192eu chipset out of the box?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731809/will-ubuntu-16-04-support-the-rtl8192eu-chipset-out-of-the-box)

and it's working fine for me now.

**Device: Tenda U1** ,,,
**OS: ubuntu 20.04**